# Not able to perform batch inferencing using fast-bert sagemaker model over entire test dataset

Tags: python, prediction, amazon-sagemaker, inference

it would be appreciated if someone can help me on fast-bert batch transform using sagemaker trained model.

we were able to get the output for single JSON record, but when applying over the entire test data(in JSON format) it is giving the following error. **"TypeError: string indices must be integers"**
test data: {"text": "test text data 1"}
{"text": "test text data 2"}

**trained model:**

```
estimator = 
sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(image,role,train_instance_count=1,train_instance_type='ml.p3.8xlarge', output_path=output_path, base_job_name=trn_config.get("base_job_name"), hyperparameters=hyperparameters,sagemaker_session=session

                                     )
```

batch transform function used:

```
bert_transformer = estimator.transformer(
    instance_count=1, 
    instance_type='ml.m5.large', 
    output_path=batch_output,
    accept = "application/jsonlines"
)

bert_transformer.transform(
    data=batch_input,
    content_type='application/json',
    split_type='Line'
)
```

Single record passed to the model: {"text": "sample text description"}
output: [["30428", 0.9663759469985962], ["28135", 0.008436146192252636], ["27615", 0.0028499893378466368], ["30416", 0.001644121715798974], ["29071", 0.001503797248005867], ["30816", 0.001284519792534411], ["30276", 0.0009555158321745694], ["27343", 0.0007992553873918951], ["27206", 0.0007786208298057318], ["26316", 0.00075926398858428]]

above mentioned batch transform function is working for single JSON record like shown above, but giving error for multiple records. I tried passing different formats of JSON data, didn't work out.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippets provided It looks like you are not setting the `MultiRecord` strategy to process the multiple lines in your json.

```
 pca_transformer = pca.transformer(
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m4.xlarge",
    strategy="MultiRecord",
    assemble_with="Line",
    output_path="s3://{}/{}/pca/transform/train".format(bucket, prefix),
)
```

Take a look at the example [`here`](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker_batch_transform/introduction_to_batch_transform/batch_transform_pca_dbscan_movie_clusters.html)